# NGINX, FastCGI, UTF-8 Encoding: Output iso-8859-1 instead of utf8

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, nginx, cgi, fastcgi

i hope you can give me an idea about what's going wrong.

The Szenario:
I run gitweb (CGI) with a script in fastcgi mode:

```
#!/bin/sh
export FCGI_SOCKET_PATH=127.0.0.1:7001
su git -c "/var/www/vh_[vhost]/htdocs/gitweb.cgi --fastcgi &"
```

Then i use nginx to serve that content:

```
...
fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:7001; 
...
```

Everything works as expected, but here's the problem:

```
$ wget "http://git.[host].de/?p=[repo].git;a=summary" -O /tmp/test.txt && file --mime-encoding /tmp/test.txt
> /tmp/test.txt: iso-8859-1



$ su git -c "./gitweb.cgi \"?p=[repo].git;a=summary\" > ./test" && file --mime-encoding ./test 
> ./test: utf-8
```

Which obviously means that fast-cgi output is utf8 while content served by nginx is iso-8859-1.

FireBugs Response Header:

```
Server  nginx
Date    Fri, 02 Sep 2011 14:14:08 GMT
Content-Type    application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
Connection  close
```

It looks like the transfer using the socket leads to an encoding problem.
I've tested a lot but can't figure out how to solve this.

Comment: I see this problem too with nginx: Z�rich instead of Zürich ... hoping for an answer!

Comment: as per my below ... try adding the charset

Answer (score 2):

although you aren't using PHP, I found the fix for my issue but wrapping the pieces that were being exposed as ISO-8859-1 with:  `utf8_encode()`:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php

If your CGI is in PERL, maybe http://perldoc.perl.org/utf8.html will solve your problem.  It solved mine ... Z�rich

Another option could be to add the following to the `http { }` statement in your nginx.conf:

```
 charset utf-8;
```

-sd

Comment: Thx, but utf8_encode() was the first i tried :/ Actually, the perl script produces valid utf8, the problem is that nginx doesn't serve the utf8 but  ISO-8859-1 encoding, only on that script, others like php via fastcgi are served correctly.

Comment: what version of nginx?  try 1.0.x ?

Answer (score 1):

I can make it works by using `fcgiwrap`.

I though some environment variables where different between the two methods, so I added the following code to the `gitweb.cgi` `dispatch()` sub:

```perl
        open my $tmplogfile, ">", "/tmp/gitweb-env.txt";
        foreach my $varkey (sort keys %ENV) {
                print $tmplogfile "$varkey = $ENV{$varkey}\n";
        }
        close $tmplogfile;
```

but the environment were the same.

Something may be done by `fcgiwrap`, I do not yet found what.

Here are the commands I use and the differences I found using `tcpdump` on the fcgi socket:

```
# gitweb spawned by fcgiwrap outputs utf-8
/usr/bin/spawn-fcgi -d /usr/share/gitweb -a 127.0.0.1 -p 3000 -u www-data -g gitolite -P /run/gitweb/gitweb.cgi.pid -- /usr/sbin/fcgiwrap

# Require the following nginx gitweb_fastcgi_params
# fastcgi_param   QUERY_STRING            $query_string;
# fastcgi_param   REQUEST_METHOD          $request_method;
# fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME             $fastcgi_script_name;
# fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_ROOT           $document_root;

# With the following nginx configuration
# upstream gitweb {
#     server 127.0.0.1:3000;
# }
# 
# server {
#         listen   80;
# 
#         server_name git.example.net;
#
#         root /usr/share/gitweb;
#
#         access_log /var/log/nginx/gitweb-access.log;
#         error_log /var/log/nginx/gitweb-errors.log;
# 
#         location / {
#                 alias /usr/share/gitweb/gitweb.cgi;
#                 include gitweb_fastcgi_params;
#                 fastcgi_pass gitweb;
#         }
# 
#         location /static {
#                 alias /usr/share/gitweb/static;
#                 expires 31d;
#         }
# }

# STDOUT captured on lo
# Begin of the FCGI answer
#    00000000  01 06 00 01 1f f8 00 00  53 74 61 74 75 73 3a 20 ........ Status: 
#    00000010  32 30 30 20 4f 4b 0d 0a  43 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 2d 200 OK.. Content-
#    00000020  54 79 70 65 3a 20 61 70  70 6c 69 63 61 74 69 6f Type: ap plicatio
#    00000030  6e 2f 78 68 74 6d 6c 2b  78 6d 6c 3b 20 63 68 61 n/xhtml+ xml; cha
#    00000040  72 73 65 74 3d 75 74 66  2d 38 0d 0a 0d 0a 3c 3f rset=utf -8....<?
#    00000050  78 6d 6c 20 76 65 72 73  69 6f 6e 3d 22 31 2e 30 xml vers ion="1.0
#    [...]
#
# "Guido Günther" as UTF-8
#    00000FA0  6c 65 3d 22 53 65 61 72  63 68 20 66 6f 72 20 63 le="Sear ch for c
#    00000FB0  6f 6d 6d 69 74 73 20 61  75 74 68 6f 72 65 64 20 ommits a uthored 
#    00000FC0  62 79 20 47 75 69 64 6f  20 47 c3 bc 6e 74 68 65 by Guido  G..nthe
#    00000FD0  72 22 20 63 6c 61 73 73  3d 22 6c 69 73 74 22 20 r" class ="list"
```

Before, `gitweb --fastcgi` was directly spawned by `spawn-fcgi`:

```
# gitweb spawned by spawn-fcgi outputs iso-8859-1
/usr/bin/spawn-fcgi -d /usr/share/gitweb -a 127.0.0.1 -p 3000 -u www-data -g gitolite -P /run/gitweb/gitweb.cgi.pid -- /usr/share/gitweb/gitweb.cgi --fastcgi

# STDOUT captured on lo
# Begin of the FCGI answer with "00 46 02" in place of "1f f8 00" for utf-8 output
#    00000000  01 06 00 01 00 46 02 00  53 74 61 74 75 73 3a 20 .....F.. Status: 
#    00000010  32 30 30 20 4f 4b 0d 0a  43 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 2d 200 OK.. Content-
#    00000020  54 79 70 65 3a 20 61 70  70 6c 69 63 61 74 69 6f Type: ap plicatio
#    00000030  6e 2f 78 68 74 6d 6c 2b  78 6d 6c 3b 20 63 68 61 n/xhtml+ xml; cha
#    00000040  72 73 65 74 3d 75 74 66  2d 38 0d 0a 0d 0a 00 00 rset=utf -8......
#    00000050  01 06 00 01 02 88 00 00  3c 3f 78 6d 6c 20 76 65 ........ <?xml ve
#    00000060  72 73 69 6f 6e 3d 22 31  2e 30 22 20 65 6e 63 6f rsion="1 .0" enco
#    00000070  64 69 6e 67 3d 22 75 74  66 2d 38 22 3f 3e 0a 3c ding="ut f-8"?>.<
#    [...]
#
# "Guido Günther" as ISO-8859-1
#    00001128  74 6c 65 3d 22 53 65 61  72 63 68 20 66 6f 72 20 tle="Sea rch for 
#    00001138  63 6f 6d 6d 69 74 73 20  61 75 74 68 6f 72 65 64 commits  authored
#    00001148  20 62 79 20 47 75 69 64  6f 20 47 fc 6e 74 68 65  by Guid o G.nthe
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but i can't verify that after such a long time, maybe someone else can verify this solution.